# What is Han Solo’s age coinciding with the present-time of Book of Boba Fett Episode 1?

Tags: star-wars, han-solo, the-book-of-boba-fett

How old is Han Solo at the time of *The Book of Boba Fett*, Episode 1 “Stranger in a Strange Land?” (The series’ “present” time, not flashbacks)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Canon, Han was born in 32 BBY (according to *Skywalker: A Family at War*), while the series' "present day" episodes take place in about the same timeframe as *The Mandalorian*, which takes place in 9 ABY. Therefore, Han is roughly **41** during the show, the same age as Boba Fett.